# Express the symmetric difference using only complement and intersect?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How would I go about expressing the symmetric difference if the only symbols I am allowed to use are the complement and intersect symbols? I know that $A \ominus B = (A^c\cap B) \cup (B^c\cap A)$, but how to I convert it so that the union is not needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a union using complements and intersections.  Namely, you have to check that $A \cup B = (A^c \cap B^c)^c$.  This is obvious because the complement of the union is those elements which are in neither $A$ nor $B$, ie the elements in both $A^c$ and in $B^c$.

Comment: Thanks! That solved my problem.